# Task scheduler Event trigger on user mail field change

Tags: active-directory, windows-event-log, windows-server-2019, task-scheduler

How I could trigger Task Scheduler event when user mail field changed (or any custom attribute) in Active Directory?
We want to run Powershell script when user mail field changes.
Event ID: 4738, doesn't trigger when mail changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event Id 4738 is logged for attributes that are documented for that event. If you want to use other attributes, you need to use Event Id 5136 (Directory Service Changes).

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4738

Comment: I've tried Event ID 5136 but it doesn't trigger event either when I change user mail

Comment: @Prefixas: that's probably because you haven't enabled directory service change auditing. It isn't enabled by default.